# AngularJs consultar dados Enviando objeto para o filtro

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

Tenho um WS escrito no Spring que recebe um objeto como filtro e devolve uma lista de dados.

no meu Service Java:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/{filtro}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Datatable listar(@RequestBody PessoaFiltro filtro) throws Exception {
    /*Codigo não importante omitido aqui*/
}
```

no meu Service angularJS:

```
angular.module('datatablePessoaFactory', ['ngResource'])
.factory('datatablePessoaService', function($resource) {
    var recurso = $resource('/datatable-pessoa/:filtro', {filtro:'@filtro'}, 
            {'update': { method:'PUT'}
        }
    );
    return recurso;
}
```

);

a chamada no controller JS:

```
datatablePessoaService.get({'filtro':vm.filtro},
function(dados){
    vm.datatablePessoas = dados;
},            
function(erro){
    console.log(erro);
}
```

);

todavia eu não consigo realizar a consulta, pois, pelo que pude entender, o método GET não aceita a passagem de objetos complexos.

e vejo no meu console o erro:

> datatable-pessoa/%5Bobject%20Object%5D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

então minha pergunta é: Como eu posso fazer uma consulta em que seja necessário passar um objeto complexo?

Comment: Vou arriscar pq não conheco java, mas parece q a rota recebe GET e vc esta passando PUT, resultando no método não permitido de acordo com o erro retornado. Se voce colocar no JS "  {'update': { method:'GET'} " será que não resolve ?